# Why is my React code throwing an undefined error when importing my functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm currently developing an app where a number of products will be listed. When the user selects a product, they will go to Product.js where a sequence of images will be rendered relative to that product. However, currently I'm receiving an error when trying to pull in the correct list of images (ImageSequence.js) for each product.

I'm fairly new to React so if someone could help me resolve this it would be much appreciated.

The error I'm receiving is as follows:

```
Error: Cannot find module './undefined/undefined0.jpg'
```

ProductData.js

```
const ProductData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Product 1',
    slug: 'product-1',
    explore_tech_img_folder: 'product_1_explore_technologies',
    explore_tech_filename: 'product_1_explore_technologies',
    user_interface_img_folder: 'product_1_user_interface',
    user_interface_filename: 'product_1_user_interface',
    categories: ['Atomic Spectroscopy', 'Cell Cultures'],
    waterTypes: ['Type 1'],
    feedTypes: ['Mains'],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Product 2',
    slug: 'product-2',
    explore_tech_img_folder: 'product_2_explore_technologies',
    explore_tech_filename: 'product_2_explore_technologies',
    user_interface_img_folder: 'product_2_user_interface',
    user_interface_filename: 'product_2_user_interface',
    categories: ['Atomic Spectroscopy', 'DNA/RNA Work'],
    waterTypes: ['Type 1'],
    feedTypes: ['Mains'],
  },
];

export default ProductData
```

Products.js

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faArrowLeft, faArrowRight } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import ProductData from "./data/ProductData";
import { ChoicesContext } from "../context/ChoicesProvider";
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../images/logo.svg';
import { ReactComponent as WaterTechLogo } from '../images/water-tech-logo.svg';

const Products = () => {
  const { choices } = useContext(ChoicesContext);
  const ProductsResult = ProductData.filter(x => x.categories.includes(choices.category) && x.waterTypes.includes(choices.waterType) && x.feedTypes.includes(choices.feedType));

  return (
    <>
      <Link to="/">
        <Logo className="Logo" />
      </Link>
      <WaterTechLogo className="WaterTechLogo" />

      <div className="pageLinks">
        <div className="breadcrumb">Applications > {choices.category} > {choices.waterType} > {choices.feedType}</div>
        <div className="backBtn"></div>
      </div>

      <div className="products wrapper d-md-flex">

        <aside>
          <div className="wrapper">
            <h2 className="text-center text-md-left">Select a<br />Product</h2>
            <div className="scrollArrows">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} />
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </aside>

        <main>
          <div id="productResults">
            {ProductsResult.map((item, i) => (
              <div key={i} className="product">
                <Link
                  to={{
                    pathname: '/products/' + item.slug,
                    name: item.name,
                  }}
                >
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250" alt="" />
                <div className="description">
                  <h4>{item.name}</h4>
                  <p>Key Features:</p>
                  <ul className="features">
                    {item.keyFeatures.map((item, i) => (
                      <li key={i}>{item}</li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                  <p class="select"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight} /> Select</p>
                </div>
                </Link>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

SequenceImages.js

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import ProductData from "./data/ProductData";
import { ChoicesContext } from "../context/ChoicesProvider";

const SequenceImages = () => {
  const { choices } = useContext(ChoicesContext);
  const ProductSelected = ProductData.filter(x => x.name === choices.category);

  let images = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
    images.push(<img src={require(`../images/sequences/${ProductSelected.explore_tech_img_folder}/${ProductSelected.explore_tech_filename}${i}.jpg`)} alt="" className="sequenceImage" />);
  }
  return images;
};

export default SequenceImages;
```

Product.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import '../App.scss';
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../images/logo.svg';
import { ReactComponent as WaterTechLogo } from '../images/water-tech-logo.svg';
import SequenceImages from './SequenceImages';

class Product extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.forwardSequence = this.forwardSequence.bind(this);
    this.reverseSequence = this.reverseSequence.bind(this);
  }

  async sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
  }

  async forwardSequence(sequence, effect) {
    Array.prototype.reduce.call
      ( sequence
      , (r, img) => r.then(_ => this.sleep(50)).then(_ => effect(img))
      , Promise.resolve()
      )
  }

  async reverseSequence(sequence, effect) {
    Array.prototype.reduceRight.call
      ( sequence
      , (r, img) => r.then(_ => this.sleep(50)).then(_ => effect(img))
      , Promise.resolve()
      )
  }

  render() {
    const seq = document.getElementsByClassName("sequenceImage");

    return (
      <>
        <Link to="/">
          <Logo className="Logo" />
        </Link>
        <WaterTechLogo className="WaterTechLogo" />

        <div className="product wrapper d-md-flex">
          <aside>
            <h1>Product</h1>
          </aside>

          <main>
            <div className="imageSequence">
              <img src={require(`../images/sequences/static.jpg`)} alt="" className="staticImage" />
              <SequenceImages />
            </div>
            <p>xxx</p>
            <button onClick={() => this.forwardSequence(seq, img => img.style.opacity = 1)}>Forward Animation</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.reverseSequence(seq, img => img.style.opacity = 0)}>Reverse Animation</button>
          </main>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for me to answer the question if you write what error you get. Thanks

Comment: Htmm, i guess that _ProductSelected_ is an `array` type, but you are referring to his property, which, i think, does not exists
/// SequenceImages.js ==>
for (let i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
    images.push(<img src={require(`../images/sequences/${ProductSelected.explore_tech_img_folder}/${ProductSelected.explore_tech_filename}${i}.jpg`)} alt="" className="sequenceImage" />);
  }

Answer (score 0):

`const ProductSelected = ProductData.filter(x => x.name === choices.category);`

`ProductSelected` is an array.

You then try to access properties in that array in this line:
``` images.push(<img src={require(``../images/sequences/${ProductSelected.explore_tech_img_folder}/${ProductSelected.explore_tech_filename}${i}.jpg``)} alt="" className="sequenceImage" />); ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that a require can be done dynamically like you have done on the following:

```
images.push(<img 
src={require(``../images/sequences/${ProductSelected.explore_tech_img_folder}/${ProductSelected.explore_tech_filename}${i}.jpg``)} 
alt="" className="sequenceImage" />)
```

You may need to pre-require your files and put them into an object and loop over that.

```
const images = require("../images/sequences");
```

then access them by:

```
const image = images[myComponentName];
```

Webpack and in general React does not play nice with dynamic imports. This is because the requires and imports are resolved at runtime but by that time it might be too late to fetch the required contents.

and the file images/sequences should just export an object with pathnames. This possibly could be dynamically generated. As now you are accessing things not using the import/export rules.

OR

Just try getting rid of the require part of the src attribute?

```
src={`../images/sequences/${ProductSelected.explore_tech_img_folder}/${ProductSelected.explore_tech_filename}${i}.jpg`
```

Good luck and happy hacking.